# Kafka consumers - poll will bring the records from one partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

As the title of the questions says it all, I had a consumer group  CG with C1 , C2 . And a topic with 5 partitions .

C1 - > P1,P2,P3
C2 - >  P4,P5

When C1 requests records thorough poll(), in a single iteration, does it bring the records from all partitions it is subscribed to ( P1,P2,P3 in this case) or one partition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If a consumer is assigned multiple partitions to fetch data from, it will try to consume from all of them at the same time, effectively giving these partitions the same priority for consumption."

This answer is directly taken from the Apache Kafka documentation here - https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html. The heading is Consumption Flow Control.